# Are there any wireless webcams/cameras that Windows will recognize as a capture device?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, webcam

I'd like to have a webcam in a different room from my computer, and the distance means USB is out of the question.

I know there are many wireless cameras, but what I can't seem to find out is if any of them would be recognized by Windows as a capture device (just like a locally connected USB webcam).

Most of the wireless cameras I can find (e.g., D-Link DCS920; Cisco-Linksys WVC54GCA, etc.) can all stream video directly from the camera itself, which is fine if you're using the camera as a "security" camera (for private use only), but not for other uses (say, sending the video to an online video streaming service, e.g., Ustream).

It seems like this should be possible; after all, wireless (WiFi) printers with scanners are recognized by Windows.

Are there any wireless (WiFi) cameras out there that would be recognized by Windows as a capture device in the same way as a USB webcam would?

Alternatively, a camera that's not wireless (e.g., connects via Ethernet) would do the trick too - but I imagine if anyone is going to make a remote camera like this, they'd go the extra step and make it wireless, too.

Comment: I have been searching for stream to capture device for a long time, but could only find one obscure sourceforge project for a very particular manufacturer.

Comment: Hmmm... that does not bode well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a converter that changes the USB in to an RJ-45 and back to overcome the distance http://www.buyincoins.com/search--usb+cat----1.html

Comment: This is a dead link.